# How to attach toString to proxy handler

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

Consider this code:

```
handler.toString = function() {
    return Reflect.get(original,'toString');
}
handler.apply = scope.exportFunctionWithName(function(target, thisArgs, args){
    try {
        return args.length?
            replacement.call(thisArgs, ...args):
            replacement.call(thisArgs);
    }
    catch (error){
        try {
            return original.apply(thisArgs, args);
        }
        catch (error){
            return target.apply(thisArgs, args);
        }
    }
}, window, "");
const proxy = new window.Proxy(original, handler);
```

if I invoke `ApiObj.toString()`, it works as expected.

Now if I want to invoke `ApiObj.toString.caller`, it errors out, with

> get caller method called on incompatible proxy

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please include the whole definition of `handler`, `scope`, `original` and `ApiObj` as a [mcve] that we can run

Comment: Do not use `.caller`, it is deprecated since ages.